# How to Create Strings Programatically in Java

Tags: java

So I am creating a program that need to create as many strings and integers as the user says. The amount is stored in `wordlength`, and I need to create these strings programmatically based on the input. Can somebody help me?

Comment: Have you made an attempt at writing some code?

Comment: @christopher yes I have

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to read in values from the console, which there are tons of answers about already. [Example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10854928/reading-a-string-with-new-lines-from-console-java)

Comment: as a start you can start by sketcing out a sample input and output

Comment: @IanSokullu - Christopher's comment was a hint that if you have code and need help with it, you should post it in your question.

Answer (score 1):

First, ask the user to input how many strings to store. This can be done through a `Scanner`.
Then, make an array of type String with `length` equal to the user input number.
Then, fill in the array through a Scanner with a `for` loop.
I hope next time you search about you problem before you write a question about it.